# EXCEL - Comparing 2 columns and returning duplicate

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

```
1  Apple         Apricot  Match
2  Tomato        Mango .  Match
3  Apricot       Carrot   Unique
4  Mango         Potato   Unique
5  Orange        Pepper   Unique
6  Passionfruit  Salt     Unique
```

I'm trying to compare two columns and find the unique's and matches regardless of where they are in each.

I thought an IF statement would work, however it only matches against a cell if its directly next to it, not taking the whole argument into play.

```
=IF(A2=$B:B),"Match","Unique")
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: is the "mango ." correct in Col B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use match and iferror to return the text "match " with the row number of the matching item so:

```
=IFERROR("Match "&MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$6,0),"Unique")
```

I used the same data you showed, it may be a useful solution...

Just noted that mango in col B has a full stop after it - is that a typo, because it won't find a match - a combination of left(), trim(), substitute come to mind...

Answer (score 0):

You could use vlookup for this

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,$C$1:$C$6,1,0)
```

N/A values are not matching ones

[image: NA values are not found]

Comment: Use `IFERROR()` to handle errors like `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,$C$1:$C$6,1,0),"Unique")`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Match()` function with combination `if()`.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$6,0)),"Match","Unique")
```

[image]

Comment: If you found it working then you should accept my answer and up vote it.